# How do I guarantee that I have a process always up and running?

Tags: linux, daemon, supervisord, start-stop-daemon

Is it more reliable to use `daemontools` or `supervisord`, or that I use crontab that runs a script of mine to keep checking if the process still exists and if not, start it again?

What is the best way to guarantee for sure that a process is always running, and running in a healthy condition? (i.e., it isn't running but stalled in some error, where it should be killed and started again).

Btw, this is a Java process that I start like `java -jar app.jar`.

Thanks!

Comment: First, invest in UPS hardware...  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

We use `monit` for such tasks. It could run process if it is in down state

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use supervisord for my servers. It's really easy to configure and understand, and it can be configured to automatically re-run a failing process several times.

You should probably start by reading the [oficial docs](http://supervisord.org/introduction.html), specifically, [this](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings) section to set up start retries.